# Is it possible to set the task.status as Succeeded in Azure DevOps explicitly?

Tags: azure, variables, azure-devops, task, azure-pipelines

My task fails with an error but I want my overall pipeline to look as successful. Is there any option for it.

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584209/how-to-set-an-azure-devops-pipeline-result-as-success-even-if-one-of-the-job-fai

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set an azure devops pipeline result as success even if one of the job fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584209/how-to-set-an-azure-devops-pipeline-result-as-success-even-if-one-of-the-job-fai)

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We could open the pipeline and enable the feature `Continue on error`

[image]

Then the pipeline's result will be set to SucceededWithIssues when the task failed. You will have a exclamation mark instead of red Cross, check the pic below.

[image]

You could refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590299/13903626) for more details.